# iOS 12 Notification Extension custom UI not capturing UIButton tapping

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

I was creating my own Notification Extension custom UI with iOS 12 following [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/user-notifications-ios12/). I created a UIButton in my custom UI and then control-drag'n'drop the button into the NotificationViewController class in the swift file to generate the event handling like this

[image]

When I run the extension and tapped the button, nothing happened other than launching the app. I was expecting to catch the breakpoint as well as the printing message "*** joinButtonTapped" but actually this event handling code was not triggered at all. Did I miss anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Did I miss anything?

Yes. Notification content extensions are not interactive by default. If you want interactivity, you need to say so, explicitly, in the *Info.plist*. You didn’t do that.

So, in the NSExtensionAttributes in the *Info.plist*, add the UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled Boolean key and set its value to YES.

Comment: Furthermore, if I create 2 buttons, is it possible that when I tap one of the buttons, the app will be launched automatically being aware which button I tapped? How? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, that's another question; you don't get a free extra question in the comments, ask a new question! (Or you _could_ just watch the WWDC 2018 videos about notifications and learn the answer for yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have created a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544222/how-to-let-ios-12-notification-extension-custom-ui-buttons-trigger-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

simple create Boolean in info.plist under NSExtensionAttribute
UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled=YES

[image: UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled=YES]

Here is the Apple Documentation for such question kindly read it once it will clear rest of the question,

[Apple UserNotification UI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications?language=objc)